# JAVASCRIPT: Toggle within Toggle not working issue

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am a newbie, I have two toggle (will soon be 4 toggles). They work perfectly fine when they are separate but once i put them inside of one and other only one toggle works.

After a bit of research i found that adjustments must be made to my javascript, but cannot find how to do this anywhere on the web.I have found this jQuery code, that does exactly what i want to do. But because i am using a string (printing out echo's from a DB) to create my  HTML, jQuery does not Seem to work. Therefore i am using Javascript, I was wondering is there is anything similar to this in Javascript.

http://jsfiddle.net/ufC5B/2/

**My code**

```
             //toggle and change bg colour
        function toggle_visibility(id) {
            var e = document.getElementById(id);
            if (e.style.display == "block" || e.style.display == "") {
                e.style.display = "none";

            } else {
                e.style.display = "block";
                text.innerHTML = "-";

            }
        }
```

PHP

```
  echo("<button id='onclick' onclick='toggle_visibility(\"tog$i\")'> " . $_SESSION['Food_Cat_name'] . " </button>");

        echo("<div id='first_product'>");

        echo("<div id='tog$i' class ='hidden'>");

        echo("<div id='red_head'>");
        echo("<p id='menu_title'>  " . $_SESSION['Food_Cat_name'] . " </p>");
        echo("</div>");

        echo("<p >Menu Item</p>");

        //echo("<input type='button' id='new_item' value='Add new item to " . $_SESSION['Food_Cat_name'] . "' name='new_item'>");
        echo("<button id='new_item$i' onclick='toggle_visibility(\"p_form$i\")' name='new_item'>Add new item to " . $_SESSION['Food_Cat_name'] . "</button>");

        echo("<div id='p_form$i' class ='hidden'>");

        echo("<input type='text' id='prod_name' name='prod_name' value=''>");
        echo("<br>");
        echo("<textarea id='desc' name='desc' placeholder='Item description' rows='4' maxlength='200'  required ></textarea>");
        echo("<br>");
        echo("<input type='text' id='price' name='price' value=''>");
        echo("</div>");

        echo("</form>");
```

Rendered

```js
           //toggle and change bg colour
            function toggle_visibility(id) {
                var e = document.getElementById(id);
             
                if (e.style.display == "block" || e.style.display == "") {
                    e.style.display = "none";
                 
                } else {
                    e.style.display = "block";
                    text.innerHTML = "-";

                }
            }
```

```css
.hidden {
    display: none; 
}
```

```html
           <button id='onclick' onclick='toggle_visibility("tog")'> " . $_SESSION['Food_Cat_name'] . " </button>

            <div id='first_product'>");

            <div id='tog' class ='hidden'>

            <div id='red_head'>
            <p id='menu_title'>  " . $_SESSION['Food_Cat_name'] . " </p>
            </div>

            <p >Menu Item</p>

           
            <button id='new_item' onclick='toggle_visibility("p_form")' name='new_item'>Add new item to " . $_SESSION['Food_Cat_name'] . "</button>
            
            <div id='p_form' class ='hidden'>
        
            <input type='text' id='prod_name' name='prod_name' value=''>
            <br>
            <textarea id='desc' name='desc' placeholder='Item description' rows='4' maxlength='200'  required ></textarea>
            <br>
            <input type='text' id='price' name='price' value=''>
            </div>
          
            </form>
```

Comment: Please be more specific in your explanation.Try to show rendered html or view in browser and explain what you really want.I don't understand why you are telling jquery is not going to work.From where does that 'switchTextDiv' variable came from.

Comment: @KiranMuralee so sorry i was trying to be. here is an example of what i am trying to achieve http://jsfiddle.net/ufC5B/2/

Comment: ok so when the button with id 'onclick' is clicked you want the div with id='tog$i' to toggle and also on clicking button with id='ew_item$i'.you want div with id 'p_form$i' to toggle right.

Comment: can you show me the rendered html code

Comment: text.innerHTML = "-" ??.please remove that line

Comment: @KiranMuralee yes that is correct, give me a second to put that together

Comment: Ok let me know after correcting your js code,if it is working correctly

Comment: And also you can heavily optimize your code if you are using jquery with only one single line $("#"+id).toggle()

Comment: @KiranMuralee I've done it. I did try using Jquery it seems to work on my html. but no longer works with strings

Answer (score 1):

I have noticed your js function and the problem is in the line **'text.innerHTML = "-";'**.Please remove that.If you are using jquery,you can achieve your functionality by just giving the code $("#"+id).toggle() instead of

```
var e = document.getElementById(id);
            if (e.style.display == "block" || e.style.display == "") {
                e.style.display = "none";

            } else {
                e.style.display = "block";
                text.innerHTML = "-";

            }
```

Comment: You have been very helpful. Thank you very much